# An Array of Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I want to store a group of arrays containing 2 numbers in an array. But I only want 2 numbers to be stored when 5 followed by a comma and another number is entered. Essentially, what I want my program to do is read from this array of arrays and perform tasks accordingly. So if the user enters 2, I want to store (2,0) in one space of my array and move on to ask my user for the second number. But if the user types 5,10 I want the program to store (5,10) in that same array. Then my program could filter which array has only one value and which has 2 and do different tasks accordingly. My assignment requires us to not ask 2 numbers for each array which would have made it easier.

This is what I have so far and I know I'm wrong I just don't know where to go from here:

```
    int main(void)
{
    int size = 0;
    int input;
    int factor;
    int mdArrays[100][2];
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        size = i;
        scanf("%d,%d", &input, &factor);
        
        if (input != 5 && input != 9)
        {
            factor = 0;
            for (size_t j =0 ; j< 2; j++)
            {
                mdArrays[i] = input;
                mdArrays[j] = factor;
            }
                
            
        }
        else if (input == 9)
        {
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j< 2; j++)
            {
                mdArrays[i] = input;
                mdArrays[j] = factor;
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    for (size_t i =0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            printf("%d,%d", mdArrays[i[j]]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `mdArrays[i[j]]` is invalid. Use: `mdArrays[i][j]`

Comment: So, you will get as input (e.g.) _either_ `5,7` or `2` on a _single_ line. And, you need to be able to distinguish between them? Assuming you can fill an array element with the value(s), how do you want to remember the "count" for that line/array element? Do you want a separate array (e.g.) `int counts[100];`. Or, can you use a "sentinel" [a value that is _not_ a valid input number (e.g. `-1`)] that would go into `mdArrays[i][1]` to indicate there is _no_ second value?

Comment: @CraigEstey I can use a sentinel.

Comment: You can't do it without ***Checking The Return*** of `scanf("%d,%d", &input, &factor);` (you can't use any user-input or conversion function correctly without -- checking the return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues.

`size` is one too short (it should be `i + 1`).

It *may* be possible to handle `5` vs `5,23` using `scanf`. But, I prefer to use `fgets` and `strtol` and check the delimiter (e.g. whether it's `,` or not).

The `if/else` ladder logic can be simplified if we make the first test against `input == 9` to stop the loop.

According to your code, you want to force a `factor` of zero *if* `input != 5`. That doesn't make much sense to me, but I've kept that logic [for now].

That may not be what you want/need, but it was my best interpretation of your code. The main purpose is to differentiate how many numbers are on a given line. So, adjust the rest as needed.

I *think* the way you're storing/displaying the array is incorrect. I believe you want to store `input` into `mdArrays[i][0]` and `factor` into `mdArrays[i][1]`. Using `j` makes no sense to me.

As I mentioned [in my top comments], the `printf` in the final loop is invalid.

Note that the code is cleaner if we *don't* hardwire the dimensions with a *literal* `100` in *multiple* places (e.g. once in the `myArrays` declaration and again in the outer `for` loop). Better to use (e.g.) `#define MAXCOUNT 100` and replace `100` elsewhere with `MAXCOUNT` (see below).

I created three versions. One that is annotated with original and fixed code. Another that removes the original code. And, a third that organizes the data using a `struct`.

---

Here's the refactored code. I've bracketed your/old code [vs. my/new code] with:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif
```

I added a debug `printf`. Anyway, here's the code with some annotations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int size = 0;
    int input;
    int factor;
    int mdArrays[100][2];

    for (size_t i = 0;  i < 100;  i++) {
#if 0
        size = i;
        scanf("%d,%d",&input,&factor);
#else
        // get line
        char buf[100];
        char *cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // strip newline -- only needed for debug print
        cp = strchr(buf,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;

        // decode first number
        input = strtol(buf,&cp,10);

        // decode second number if it exists -- otherwise, use a sentinel
        if (*cp == ',')
            factor = strtol(cp + 1,&cp,10);
        else
            factor = -1;

        printf("DEBUG: buf='%s' input=%d factor=%d\n",buf,input,factor);
#endif

        // stop input if we see the end marker
        if (input == 9)
            break;

        // remember number of array elements
        size = i + 1;

        // only use a non-zero factor if input is _not_ 5
        if (input != 5) {
            factor = 0;
#if 0
            for (size_t j = 0;  j < 2;  j++) {
                mdArrays[i] = input;
                mdArrays[j] = factor;
            }
            continue;
#endif
        }

#if 0
        for (int j = 0;  j < 2;  j++) {
            mdArrays[i] = input;
            mdArrays[j] = factor;
        }
#else
        mdArrays[i][0] = input;
        mdArrays[i][1] = factor;
#endif
    }

    for (size_t i = 0;  i < size;  i++) {
#if 0
        for (size_t j = 0;  j < 2;  j++) {
            printf("%d,%d",mdArrays[i[j]]);
        }
#else
        printf("%d,%d\n",mdArrays[i][0],mdArrays[i][1]);
#endif
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the sample input I used to test:

```
5,3
7,6
8,9
5,37
5
9,23
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
DEBUG: buf='5,3' input=5 factor=3
DEBUG: buf='7,6' input=7 factor=6
DEBUG: buf='8,9' input=8 factor=9
DEBUG: buf='5,37' input=5 factor=37
DEBUG: buf='5' input=5 factor=-1
DEBUG: buf='9,23' input=9 factor=23
5,3
7,0
8,0
5,37
5,-1
```

---

Here's a slightly cleaned up version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXCOUNT    100

int
main(void)
{
    int size = 0;
    int input;
    int factor;
    int mdArrays[MAXCOUNT][2];

    for (size_t i = 0;  i < MAXCOUNT;  i++) {
        // get line
        char buf[100];
        char *cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // strip newline -- only needed for debug print
#ifdef DEBUG
        cp = strchr(buf,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;
#endif

        // decode first number
        input = strtol(buf,&cp,10);

        // decode second number if it exists -- otherwise, use a sentinel
        if (*cp == ',')
            factor = strtol(cp + 1,&cp,10);
        else
            factor = -1;

#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("DEBUG: buf='%s' input=%d factor=%d\n",buf,input,factor);
#endif

        // stop input if we see the end marker
        if (input == 9)
            break;

        // remember number of array elements
        size = i + 1;

        // only use a non-zero factor if input is _not_ 5
        if (input != 5)
            factor = 0;

        mdArrays[i][0] = input;
        mdArrays[i][1] = factor;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0;  i < size;  i++)
        printf("%d,%d\n",mdArrays[i][0],mdArrays[i][1]);

    return 0;
}
```

---

You *might* benefit from using a `struct` [YMMV], so here's a version that keeps things organized that way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXCOUNT    100

typedef struct {
    int input;
    int factor;
} data_t;

int
main(void)
{
    int size = 0;
    data_t mdArrays[MAXCOUNT];
    data_t *data;

    for (size_t i = 0;  i < MAXCOUNT;  i++) {
        // get line
        char buf[100];
        char *cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // strip newline -- only needed for debug print
#ifdef DEBUG
        cp = strchr(buf,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;
#endif

        data = &mdArrays[i];

        // decode first number
        data->input = strtol(buf,&cp,10);

        // decode second number if it exists -- otherwise, use a sentinel
        if (*cp == ',')
            data->factor = strtol(cp + 1,&cp,10);
        else
            data->factor = -1;

#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("DEBUG: buf='%s' input=%d factor=%d\n",buf,input,factor);
#endif

        // stop input if we see the end marker
        if (data->input == 9)
            break;

        // remember number of array elements
        size = i + 1;

        // only use a non-zero factor if input is _not_ 5
        if (data->input != 5)
            data->factor = 0;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0;  i < size;  i++) {
        data = &mdArrays[i];
        printf("%d,%d\n",data->input,data->factor);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read a line of user input with `fgets()` and then parse it to see if it is one number, two comma separated numbers or something else.

I recommend using `"%n" to detect when and how scanning finished.

```
int get_numbers(int *input, int *factor) {
  char buf[80];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(buf, "%d %n", input, &n);
    if (n > 0 && buf[n] == '\0') return 1;
    n = 0; 
    sscanf(buf, "%d ,%d %n", input, factor, &n);
    if (n > 0 && buf[n] == '\0') return 2;
    return 0; // Invalid input
  }
  return EOF;  // No input
}
```

Usage

```
// scanf("%d,%d", &input, &factor);
switch (get_numbers(&input, &factor)) {
  case 2: printf("%d %d\n", input, factor); break;
  case 1: printf("%d\n", input); break;
  case 0: printf("Invalid input\n"); break;
  case EOF: printf("No input\n"); break;
}
```