# Drawing in 2D Arrays Turtle Graphics

Tags: c++, arrays, c, multidimensional-array, graphics

I am trying to recreate the Turtle Graphics in C but my program is not giving me what I want. My "Turtle" is supposed to start with the pen up and facing east but instead, it starts off by facing south. I have decided to give numbered variables to directions so I can manage them easily. So 3 is East, 6 is South, 9 is West, and 12 is North My 0,0 position is on the top left of the array. And to navigate there are commands the user can use to change direction, decide when to put the pen up or down and when to print.

When I enter the commands 2(pen down), 5,15 (move 15 spaces), 6(print) and 9 (Show Result) this is what it gives me:

```
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
```

instead of this:

```
***************
```

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int facing = 3; //start by facing east
int pen = 1; //start by pen up
int copyToArrays(int commandCheck[2][2], const int commands);
int readCommand(int commandCheck[]);
void performCommand(const int command, const int factor, int floor[50][50]);
void draw(const int floor[50][50]);
// y and x coordinates of turtle
int posX =0;
int posY =0;

int main(void)
{
    //INSTRUCTIONS
    printf("Command Key: \n\n");
    printf("1 ---- pen up\n");
    printf("2 ---- pen down\n");
    printf("3 ---- turn right\n");
    printf("4 ---- turn left\n");
    printf("5, N ---- move forward N spaces\n");
    printf("6 ---- Print 50 by 50 Floor\n");
    printf("9 ---- End Data\n\n");
   
    printf("Enter your commands.\n");
    int floor[50][50] = {{0}, {0}};// floor of length and width of 50
    int commandArrays[100][2] = {{0}, {0}};// arrays for the commands
    int numberOfCommands = 0;
    
    numberOfCommands = copyToArrays(commandArrays, 100);// calculate how many commands to process
    
    //for loop to go through the commands and perform them one by one
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numberOfCommands; i++)
    {
        performCommand(commandArrays[i][0], commandArrays[i][1], floor);
    }
}


// function to copy commands into arrays and return the number of commands 
int copyToArrays(int commandArray[2][2], const int commands)
{
    int i;
    int commandCheck[2];
    for ( i  = 0; i <commands && readCommand(commandCheck); i++)
    {
        commandArray[i][0] = commandCheck[0];
        commandArray[i][1] = commandCheck[1];
    }
    
    return i;
}

// Function to take input commands from user while checking if it is a move command or not
int readCommand(int commandCheck[])
{
    scanf("%d,%d", &commandCheck[0], &commandCheck[1]);
    
    if(commandCheck[0] != 5)
    {
        commandCheck[1] = 0;
    }
    
    if(commandCheck[0] == 9)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}


// read command and perform task accordingly
void performCommand(const int command, const int factor, int floor[50][50])
{
    int j; 
    switch(command)
    {
        case 1: pen = 1;
            break;
        case 2: pen = 0;
            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
            break;
        case 3: if (facing == 3)
                   {
                    facing = 6;
                   }
               else if (facing == 6)
               {
                facing  = 9;
               } 
               else if (facing == 9)
               {
                facing = 12;
               }
               else if (facing == 12)
               {
                facing  = 3;
               }
               break;
          case 4: if (facing == 3)
                   {
                    facing = 12;
                   }
               else if (facing == 12)
               {
                facing  = 9;
               } 
               else if (facing == 9)
               {
                facing = 6;
               }
               else if (facing == 6)
               {
                facing  = 3;
               }
               break;
           
           case 5: if (facing == 3)
                   {
                    for (j = 1; j <= factor; j++)
                    {
                        posX++;
                        if(pen == 0)
                        {
                            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    
                   }
                   else if (facing == 6)
                   {
                    for(j = 1; j <= factor; j++)
                    {
                        posY--;
                        if(pen == 0)
                        {
                            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                   }
                   else if (facing == 9)
                   {
                    for(j = 1; j <= factor; j++)
                    {
                        posX--;
                        if(pen == 0)
                        {
                            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                   }
                   else if(facing == 12)
                   {
                    for(j = 1; j <= factor; j++)
                    {
                        posY++;
                        if(pen == 0)
                        {
                            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                   }
                   break;
            case 6: draw(floor);
                    break;
            default:
            break;
    }
}


//FUntion to draw on the floor
void draw(const int floor[50][50])
{
    
     printf("\n");
     for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
     {
        for(int j = 0; j < 49; j++)
        {
            if(floor[i][j] == 1)
            {
                printf("%s", "*");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        puts("");
     }
}
```

Comment: Because only the "5" command takes an extra argument, I don't think you can use a simple `scanf("%d,%d",...);` as is. See my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64979351/an-array-of-arrays/64980013#64980013 for a way to read in the commands.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, consider using `std::vector<std::vector<>>`.  It's easier to pass to functions (by reference) than arrays.

Comment: Instead of `printf("%s", "*");` to print 1 character, consider `putchar('*');`

Comment: Because your `draw` does `i` and `j` loops in the wrong order. Put the `j` loop on the outside and everything should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are executing the "move" command (command is `5`) [or "pen down" as well], you are transposing the indexes.

That is, you do:

```
floor[posX][posY] = 1;
```

But, what you want is:

```
floor[posY][posX] = 1;
```

---

When printing, you are doing:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < 49;  i++) {
    for (int j = 0;  j < 49;  j++) {
```

But, what you want is:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < 50;  i++) {
    for (int j = 0;  j < 50;  j++) {
```

---

Some additional cleanups ...

The "turn right" and "turn left" can be simplified with a `switch`. But, they can also be a simple addition/subtraction.

The "move" command doesn't need four separate `for` loops if we define two variables (e.g. `incX` and `incY`)

Here's the full code with the bugs fixes and the cleanups. The convention I used is to delineate old vs new code with `cpp` conditionals:

```
#if 0
// old code ...
#else
// new code ...
#endif
```

Here are the changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int copyToArrays(int commandCheck[2][2],const int commands);
int readCommand(int commandCheck[]);
void performCommand(const int command,const int factor,int floor[50][50]);
void draw(const int floor[50][50]);

int facing = 3; //start by facing east
int pen = 1; //start by pen up

// y and x coordinates of turtle
int posX = 0;
int posY = 0;

int
main(void)
{
    //INSTRUCTIONS
    printf("Command Key: \n\n");
    printf("1 ---- pen up\n");
    printf("2 ---- pen down\n");
    printf("3 ---- turn right\n");
    printf("4 ---- turn left\n");
    printf("5,N ---- move forward N spaces\n");
    printf("6 ---- Print 50 by 50 Floor\n");
    printf("9 ---- End Data\n\n");

    printf("Enter your commands.\n");
    int floor[50][50] = {{0},{0}};// floor of length and width of 50
    int commandArrays[100][2] = {{0},{0}};// arrays for the commands
    int numberOfCommands = 0;

    // calculate how many commands to process
    numberOfCommands = copyToArrays(commandArrays,100);

    //for loop to go through the commands and perform them one by one
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < numberOfCommands;  i++) {
        performCommand(commandArrays[i][0],commandArrays[i][1],floor);
    }
}


// function to copy commands into arrays and return the number of commands
int
copyToArrays(int commandArray[2][2],const int commands)
{
    int i;
    int commandCheck[2];
    for (i  = 0;  i <commands && readCommand(commandCheck);  i++) {
        commandArray[i][0] = commandCheck[0];
        commandArray[i][1] = commandCheck[1];
    }

    return i;
}

// Function to take input commands from user while checking if it is a move
// command or not
int
readCommand(int commandCheck[])
{

    commandCheck[0] = -3;
    commandCheck[1] = -3;

    scanf("%d,%d",&commandCheck[0],&commandCheck[1]);

#if 0
    printf("DEBUG: %d,%d\n",commandCheck[0],commandCheck[1]);
#endif

    if (commandCheck[0] != 5) {
        commandCheck[1] = 0;
    }

    if (commandCheck[0] == 9) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

// read command and perform task accordingly
void
performCommand(const int command,const int factor,int floor[50][50])
{
    int j;
#if 1
    int incX = 0;
    int incY = 0;
#endif

    switch (command) {
    case 1:
        pen = 1;
        break;

    case 2:
        pen = 0;
#if 0
        floor[posX][posY] = 1;
#else
        floor[posY][posX] = 1;
#endif
        break;

    case 3:
#if 0
        if (facing == 3) {
            facing = 6;
        }
        else if (facing == 6) {
            facing  = 9;
        }
        else if (facing == 9) {
            facing = 12;
        }
        else if (facing == 12) {
            facing  = 3;
        }
#endif
#if 0
        switch (facing) {
        case 3:
            facing = 6;
            break;
        case 6:
            facing = 9;
            break;
        case 9:
            facing = 12;
            break;
        case 12:
            facing = 3;
            break;
        }
#endif
#if 1
        facing += 3;
        if (facing > 12)
            facing -= 12;
#endif
        break;

    case 4:
#if 0
        if (facing == 3) {
            facing = 12;
        }
        else if (facing == 12) {
            facing  = 9;
        }
        else if (facing == 9) {
            facing = 6;
        }
        else if (facing == 6) {
            facing  = 3;
        }
#endif
#if 0
        switch (facing) {
        case 3:
            facing = 12;
            break;
        case 6:
            facing = 3;
            break;
        case 9:
            facing = 6;
            break;
        case 12:
            facing = 9;
            break;
        }
#endif
#if 1
        facing -= 3;
        if (facing <= 0)
            facing += 12;
#endif
        break;

    case 5:
#if 0
        if (facing == 3) {
            for (j = 1;  j <= factor;  j++) {
                posX++;
                if (pen == 0) {
                    floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (facing == 6) {
            for (j = 1;  j <= factor;  j++) {
                posY--;
                if (pen == 0) {
                    floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (facing == 9) {
            for (j = 1;  j <= factor;  j++) {
                posX--;
                if (pen == 0) {
                    floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (facing == 12) {
            for (j = 1;  j <= factor;  j++) {
                posY++;
                if (pen == 0) {
                    floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
#else
        switch (facing) {
        case 3:
            incX = 1;
            break;
        case 6:
            incY = -1;
            break;
        case 9:
            incX = -1;
            break;
        case 12:
            incY = 1;
            break;
        }
        for (j = 1;  j <= factor;  j++) {
            posX += incX;
            posY += incY;
            if (pen == 0) {
#if 0
                floor[posX][posY] = 1;
#else
                floor[posY][posX] = 1;
#endif
            }
        }
#endif
        break;

    case 6:
        draw(floor);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}


//FUntion to draw on the floor
void
draw(const int floor[50][50])
{

    printf("\n");

#if 0
    for (int i = 0;  i < 49;  i++) {
        for (int j = 0;  j < 49;  j++) {
            if (floor[i][j] == 1) {
                printf("%s","*");
            }
            else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        puts("");
    }
#else
    for (int i = 0;  i < 50;  i++) {
        for (int j = 0;  j < 50;  j++) {
            if (floor[i][j] == 1) {
                putchar('*');
            }
            else {
                putchar(' ');
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
#endif
}
```

---

Here is the fully cleaned up version.

It also adds a check for going beyond the edges (by wrapping). And, it adds `#define` for the literals (e.g. `50`, `100`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM_Y   50
#define DIM_X   50

int copyToArrays(int commandCheck[2][2],const int commands);
int readCommand(int commandCheck[]);
void performCommand(const int command,const int factor,int floor[DIM_Y][DIM_X]);
void draw(const int floor[DIM_Y][DIM_X]);

int facing = 3; //start by facing east
int pen = 1; //start by pen up

// y and x coordinates of turtle
int posX = 0;
int posY = 0;

#define MAXCMD  100

int
main(void)
{
    //INSTRUCTIONS
    printf("Command Key: \n\n");
    printf("1 ---- pen up\n");
    printf("2 ---- pen down\n");
    printf("3 ---- turn right\n");
    printf("4 ---- turn left\n");
    printf("5,N ---- move forward N spaces\n");
    printf("6 ---- Print %d by %d Floor\n",DIM_Y,DIM_X);
    printf("9 ---- End Data\n\n");

    printf("Enter your commands.\n");
    int floor[DIM_Y][DIM_X] = {{0},{0}};// floor of length and width of 50
    int commandArrays[MAXCMD][2] = {{0},{0}};// arrays for the commands
    int numberOfCommands = 0;

    // calculate how many commands to process
    numberOfCommands = copyToArrays(commandArrays,MAXCMD);

    //for loop to go through the commands and perform them one by one
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < numberOfCommands;  i++) {
        performCommand(commandArrays[i][0],commandArrays[i][1],floor);
    }
}


// function to copy commands into arrays and return the number of commands
int
copyToArrays(int commandArray[MAXCMD][2],const int commands)
{
    int i;
    int commandCheck[2];
    for (i  = 0;  i < commands && readCommand(commandCheck);  i++) {
        commandArray[i][0] = commandCheck[0];
        commandArray[i][1] = commandCheck[1];
    }

    return i;
}

// Function to take input commands from user while checking if it is a move
// command or not
int
readCommand(int commandCheck[])
{

    commandCheck[0] = -3;
    commandCheck[1] = -3;

    scanf("%d,%d",&commandCheck[0],&commandCheck[1]);

#if 0
    printf("DEBUG: %d,%d\n",commandCheck[0],commandCheck[1]);
#endif

    if (commandCheck[0] != 5)
        commandCheck[1] = 0;

    return (commandCheck[0] != 9);
}

int
move(int pos,int inc,int dim)
{
    pos += inc;

    if (pos < 0)
        pos += dim;

    if (pos >= dim)
        pos -= dim;

    return pos;
}

// read command and perform task accordingly
void
performCommand(const int command,const int factor,int floor[DIM_Y][DIM_X])
{
    int j;
    int incX = 0;
    int incY = 0;

    switch (command) {
    case 1:
        pen = 1;
        break;

    case 2:
        pen = 0;
        floor[posY][posX] = 1;
        break;

    case 3:
        facing += 3;
        if (facing > 12)
            facing -= 12;
        break;

    case 4:
        facing -= 3;
        if (facing <= 0)
            facing += 12;
        break;

    case 5:
        switch (facing) {
        case 3:
            incX = 1;
            break;
        case 6:
            incY = -1;
            break;
        case 9:
            incX = -1;
            break;
        case 12:
            incY = 1;
            break;
        }
        for (j = 1;  j <= factor;  j++) {
            posX = move(posX,incX,DIM_X);
            posY = move(posY,incY,DIM_Y);
            if (pen == 0)
                floor[posY][posX] = 1;
        }
        break;

    case 6:
        draw(floor);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

//FUntion to draw on the floor
void
draw(const int floor[DIM_Y][DIM_X])
{

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0;  i < DIM_Y;  i++) {
        for (int j = 0;  j < DIM_X;  j++) {
            if (floor[i][j] == 1)
                putchar('*');
            else
                putchar(' ');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead.

```
void draw(const int floor[50][50])
{
    
     printf("\n");
     for(int j = 0; j < 49; j++)
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
        {
            if(floor[i][j] == 1)
            {
                printf("%s", "*");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        puts("");
     }
}
```

Your code is iterating through `y` on the inner loop. That means you're transposing the matrix since you're printing in the x direction (columns). The alternative would be to get rid of the silly multidimensional array syntax - really, it causes more problems than it solves - and stick to a 1D array of Width*Height dimensions, each element indexed by `y * width + x`. This eliminates any ambiguity, removes nested loops, etc. It's also the way everyone in this field does it.